# CSS changes does not seen working with JSF

Tags: css, jsf

I have a project I am developing in JSF 2.0.
I changed my styles.css file by adding a new class and changing my element in the XHTML file to the new name in the CSS file. In Eclipse clean and build the project restart the server, call the page again. 
I can see my elements' class by clicking show source of page in browser, and clicking styles.css and can see my changes.
But in both Chrome's developer tools and Firefox's Firebug I can not see the changes in styles.css in bottom right corner, where dev tools show related CSS code lines.
Where am I wrong?

CSS code:

```
ul{ width:420px; float:left}
ul li{ width:420px; float:left; font-size:16px; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px}
ul li a{ width:300px; height:40px; float:left; background:url(../images/bg_no_selected.gif) no-repeat; color:#CCCCCC; text-decoration:none; padding:20px 0 0 23px}
ul li a:hover{background:url(../images/bg_tick_hover.gif) no-repeat; color:#999999}
ul li a.passive{background:url(../images/bg_no_selected.gif) no-repeat; color:#CCCCCC}
ul li a.active{background:url(../images/bg_tick_hover.gif) no-repeat; color:#999999}
```

XHTML code:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat var="questionOption" varStatus="currentInMany" value="#{something}" id="repeatIn">
        <li>
            <h:outputLink styleClass="#{(some control which is returning false, i can see class='passive' in browser in source)?'active':'passive'}" value="javascript:void(0);" id="link">

            <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" listener="#{some method}" />

            <h:outputText value="#{some text}" />
            </h:outputLink>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post relevant HTML/CSS source code

Comment: I assume you are running this from an Integrated Eclipse server?  Check the deployment location and make sure that the updated stylesheet exists on the server deployment.  Also try clearing your browser cache.